# del or erase command support for Recycle Bin

Tags: windows-7, cmd

Is there an option to have Win7 cmd.exe's del/erase command to support moving the files to the Recycle Bin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a powershell script but you will have issues with deletion confirmation.

So, my best suggestion is to try an utility called cmdUtils and Recycle binary as mentionned here : https://superuser.com/questions/24662/what-is-the-command-line-way-of-sending-files-to-the-recycle-bin

Comment: `cmd.exe` is neither 16-bit nor MS-DOS.

Comment: cmd.exe no but cmd.exe's del/erase are. I would suggest this reading http://support.microsoft.com/kb/120681/en-us (quite old but still up to date)

Comment: Too old indeed. `cmd.exe` is just a text-mode (or console) shell, nothing to do with either 16-bit or MS-DOS applications. `DEL` or `ERASE` cannot possibly be something else because they are internal commands. Even if they were external ones, they would still be Windows console commands, either 32-bit or 64-bit, same as the OS. I agree that `cmd.exe` doesn't support Recycle Bin, I just disagree that it can be called MS-DOS.

Comment: They can't be 16 bit because 16 bit programs do not run on 64 bit, and my Win7 is 64 bit but has the cmd.exe del/erase command.  Adjust your answer accordingly and I'll mark it as "answered".

Comment: ok you are all right, i update my post to remove wrong infos. Thanks to point me this, no need to be so nervous, i was just trying to help :D